# Creating Geometrie_bar with 2 Arguments

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to build a "complex" `ggplot` with `geom_bar`

So my `data.frame` looks like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(Attribut = c("Text1", "Text2", "Text3", "Text4"), 
                 AA_P1 = c("0.111","0.32","0.16","0.332"),
                 AB_P1 = c("0.41","0.621","0.962","0.23"))
```

And my two bar-charts like this:

```
s3 = ggplot(df, aes(x = Attribut, y= AA_P1)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="blue") +
        theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1)) +
        coord_flip()

s4 = ggplot(df, aes(x = Attribut, y= AB_P1)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="red") + 
        theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1)) +
        coord_flip()
```

So my goal is to combine these two `geom_bar`'s to one by putting the data frame row `AA_P1` and `AB_P2` as bars in the same graph on the same axis.

Simultaneously is it possible to round the variables `AA_P1` and `AB_P2` to two decimal points in the plot?

Maybe this question is an easy one but I'm a total beginner in `R` and I couldn't find a feasibly solution for my problem.

Any help would be amazing :)
Regards,
Lukas

Answer (score 0):

If I get what you mean, you need to cast the `dataframe` in a tidy(er) format

```r
df <- data.frame(Attribut = c("Text1", "Text2", "Text3", "Text4"), 
                 AA_P1 = c("0.111","0.32","0.16","0.332"),
                 AB_P1 = c("0.41","0.621","0.962","0.23"))

library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% 
  gather(key, value, -Attribut) %>% 
  mutate(value = round(as.numeric(value), 2))

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_col(aes(Attribut, round(value, 2), fill = key), position='dodge')
#> Warning: attributes are not identical across measure variables;
#> they will be dropped
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-09 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Looks really good, thank you!
But how can i build the same graphic, if my data.frame looks like following:
df <- data.frame( Attribut = c("Text1", "Text2", "Text3", "Text4"), AA_P1 = c("0.11","0.32","0.16","0.33"), AB_P1 = c("0.41","0.62","0.96","0.23"), AB_P2 = c("0.51","0.22","0.76","0.63"),BB_1 = c("NA","NA","NA","NA"), ,BB_2 = c("NA","NA","NA","NA"))

My Goal is still just show up AA_P1 and AB_P1 und cut of BB_1 and BB_2 out of the tiyded dataframe?

Sorry for asking something stupid like this.

Comment: df %>% select(-BB_1, -BB_2)